# Criptografia dupla

Tags: .net, criptografia

Um colega me disse que criou uma classe de criptografia que implementa 4 algoritmos:

[TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledescryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx)

[DESCryptoServiceProvider Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.descryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx)

[RC2CryptoServiceProvider Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rc2cryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx)

[RijndaelManaged Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Ele me disse que fez, ou faria, uma criptografia sobre a outra, por exemplo:

- receberia um texto, iria criptografar com o primeiro algoritmo
- pegaria o resultado criptografado, e iria criptografar com um segundo algoritmo

Ao ouvir isso, achei meio estranho. Nunca tinha ouvido nada parecido. Pesquisei alguns termos em inglês e achei nada. Fiquei na dúvida se isso seria mais uma gambiarra na tentativa de criar uma criptografia nova, ou se seria algo bem pensado que realmente seria difícil de ser quebrado.

Creio que não será tão performático por ter que processar duas criptografias. Usar essa técnica aumenta a segurança ou o correto é optar por apenas um algoritmo?

Comment: Normal. Nós também temos uma classe própria para criptografar e descriptografar e não são raros os casos que a informação é criptografada várias vezes. E no caso o algorítimo é o mesmo, porém executado mais de uma vez.

Answer (score 5):

Isso se chama **criptografia em cascata** ([*cascade encryption*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_encryption)), e é sim utilizado em sistemas reais (por exemplo, o sistema Truecrypt oferece a opção de usar até 3 algoritmos distintos - AES, Twofish e Serpent - inclusive em diferentes ordens). A ideia é que se um ou mais algoritmos forem quebrados no futuro, tem mais chance de que pelo menos um deles permaneça seguro, e assim o conjunto continue intacto.

*Nota:* é muito importante que cada algoritmo seja usado com uma chave *distinta*, gerada de forma independente das demais. So contrário a quebra de qualquer um deles poderia revelar a chave correspondente ao atacante, e então bastaria usar essa chave para decifrar os outros, sem necessidade de quebrá-los também.

Sobre a performance, de fato é uma solução mais lenta que usar um único algoritmo, e na ausência de uma quebra criptográfica não oferece nenhuma proteção adicional em relação a usar um único algoritmo. É preciso uma análise de custo/benefício para se decidir entre usar ou não usar, e isso varia de caso a caso. Na minha experiência pessoal, um "disco rígido virtual" protegido com 3 camadas não degradou a performance de modo perceptível, ao menos para um volume moderado de acessos (a criação do disco, no entanto, levou várias horas a mais que usando um único algoritmo).